# With EJS templates deep urls wont resolve the public resources properly

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Im using ejs as template engine with default layout off, but i activate it on demand via {layout:True}, i have two urls '/' and '/session/new' the css and js are show OK in the former but in the second one they would adress to 'http://localhost/**sessions**/public/stylesheets/my.css'

i tried using *stylesheet_link_tag* as seen here (http://railwayjs.com/), but i guess its only for railwayjs, is there anything im missing,

im thinking of a workaround of addind a depth variable to precede the link and that would be filled with '/..' depending on the route

here is my configure

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('view options', {layout: false});
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  });
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  Does anyone have a better solution than the one suggested by the OP?

Comment: Refer them as "/stylesheets/my.css" in your views.
express's static middleware will be used to give response and resolved url will be of stylesheets/my.css

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe I didn't try that.  Should be added as an answer, though.